# Need some controllers in landscape

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, landscape

I have complex application with lot of ViewControllers. The whole app is designed to be in portrait mode and its locked to it.

Now I need part of app to be able to show content in landscape. Everything is working fine, excluding one scenario:

I'm on controller, which is locked to portrait and has device in landscape position - I navigate to new controller, which is landscape enabled. Then the new controller doesn't rotate to landscape. If I rotate phone to portrait and landscape again, the controller rotates correctly (if I enter the new controller with device in portrait, everything is fine and window rotates, if I rotate device. 
I tried:

```
let value = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

in viewWillAppear, but it didn't work (I suppose it can't work, because `UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation` is in requested orientation already.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your code and see if you get the results you are expecting.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
   UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
   shouldAutorotate()
}


override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    switch UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation {
    case .Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown, .Unknown:
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt help. If I read this peace of code right, it prevents to show landscape. I need nearly the opposite - hypothetically when Im holding phone in landscape all the time Im using my app, I need to rotate the screen, when I entered part of app, where is landscape enabled. If I rotate phone to portrait and back to landscape, it works.

Comment: This is the code I use in an app that if the device is in landscape that it changes it portrait mode.  Then in the in my segue I allow it to rotate back to landscape.